# Is it possible to install LXD directly on a Ubuntu Snappy Core?

Tags: lxc, ubuntu-core

I'm running a Ubuntu Snappy Core (2015-04-28, version 45).  I want to install LXD directly on the snappy host.  Is this possible?  Thx!  --todd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, definitely... But there aren't many snappy packages (snaps) yet, and lxd isn't one of them.

Update! Read the other answers, there are ways to do this now.

Comment: LXD is now available as a snappy package.

Comment: i regret posting this now :) But I agree with the down votes: not relevant correct answer anymore

Answer (score 5):

LXD is now packaged as a snap and updated reasonably often to match new upstream releases. You can install it with:

```
sudo snap install lxd
```

More details here too:

- https://stgraber.org/2016/10/17/lxd-snap-available/
- https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/getting-started-cli/